# What is "BIOS grub spacer"?

Tags: server, partitioning, grub2, bios

While installing Ubuntu Server in Virtualbox I came across this, and I wanted to know what it is because I am unable to find anything on Google:

[image]

Comment: It often called the bios_grub and is 1 or 2MB with gpt partitioned drives. Only required with BIOS boot on gpt drives.  With MBR(msdos) partitioned drives grub has core.img (extra code) in the sectors just after the MBR and before first partition. With gpt, the MBR is just a protective MBR and gpt partition table starts immediately, so no room for core.img. When I only had BIOS and started conversion to gpt, I used bios_grub. When first starting to convert to UEFI boot, I partitioned all drives with both bios_grub and an ESP - efi system partition. Only one required, but then can convert.

Answer (score 2):

A partition boundary introduced with UEFI. It aligns the partitions.

[You did not find this one?](https://github.com/canonical/subiquity/blob/main/po/pl.po)

```
#: ../subiquity/common/filesystem/labels.py:81
msgid "BIOS grub spacer"
msgstr ""
```

It is partition type 81.

Comment: I didn't even know what partitions alignments were. See https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Partition_Alignment_detailed_explanation